# Is this a good way to determine when to return an empty List for the scenario described?

Tags: c#, linq, list, getter

I have a class called Division that contains information about Subdivisions (in an internal List), including a classification code for each subdivision. In the Subdivision class, the code is stored as an int. In the Division class, a List is used to store all the codes. On occasion, there will be a Division with no Subdivisions, hence no codes. Or, for whatever reason, a code may not have been set for a Subdivision. So it will have a default value of 0. I don't want to return a list unless it has actual codes.

```
public List<int> AllCodesList
{
    get
    {
        return (from subdivision in SubdivisionInfoList
                where subdivision.code > 0 
                select subdivision.code).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand your concern, but in my opinion returning an empty list is suitable. Better than returning a null reference for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning empty list instead of null is generally good idea as the calling code can be much simple - no need to check for null (which will be missed from time to time and cause infamous null pointer exception).

There are cases when one is interested in distinction between empty list and null, but I'd strongly recommend to review such calls and make sure method's name is clear on what would be returned, some refactoring may help to never return null. In you particular case I think returning empty array in case of "no subdivisions" is perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, although just as well could have done so with another (later) response. Thanks to all for helping confirm this. Also, appreciated the reminder of ".Any" in a LINQ query.

Answer (score 5):

If you want it to return `null`, do this:

```
public List<int> AllCodesList
{
    get
    {
        List<int> subDivisions = null;
        if (SubdivisionInfoList.Any(s => s.code > 0))
        {
            subDivisions = (from subdivision in SubdivisionInfoList
                where subdivision.code > 0 
                select subdivision.code).ToList();
        }
        return subDivisions;
    }
}
```

That said, I personally am not a fan of this, I would rather return an empty list.  You will have to make sure you have null checks when you call this property before you can do anything with the list (if any is returned).

George's suggestion:

```
public List<int> AllCodesList
{
    get
    {
        var subDivisions = (from subdivision in SubdivisionInfoList
                            where subdivision.code > 0 
                            select subdivision.code).ToList();

        if (subDivisions.Count == 0)
        {
            subDivisions = null;
        }

        return subDivisions;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest doing the tolist then checking count as you only walk the enumerable once, which could matter.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett, updated my answer. With an example using your suggestion :)  Good call.  For some reason, I like the readability of mine more, but enumerating just once is a better idea.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing my suggestion :) (p.s. you can use Count as that's a property of `List<T>`, count() would have worked too as IEnumerable<T> has it defined (and internally checks for a count property I believe).

Comment: I just didn't remember which interfaces have `.Count()` since I rely on Intellisense so much.

Answer (score 2):

It might make more sense to have subdevision.code be a `Nullable<int>` (`int?`), which can then explicitly represent the absence of a code, but yes it's probably better to return an empty list rather than null since any code that uses the list would otherwise have to do separate null checks.